# Permission denied accessing volume in docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, django

I've followed [this tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/#postgres) for deploying a web application using django, gunicorn, nginx and postgresql.

When working with the empty application in the tutorial, everything seems ok, but then I tried recreating the same configuration using my Django app, and I get a "permission denied" when trying to collect the static files.

The configuration yml is:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file: .env.pg

  django:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static:/usr/src/django/static
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/usr/src/django/static
    ports:
      - 8009:80
    depends_on:
      - django

volumes:
  database:
  static:
```

The error I get when I execute `docker-compose exec django python manage.py collectstatic --clear --noinput` is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 167, in handle
    any(self.storage.listdir(destination_path))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 315, in listdir
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/src/django/static'
```

I tried executing a shell inside the container: the "static" directory is where it is supposed to be, but I can't write anything in it (even as root).
The database volume in the postgres container seems to work fine, so I think it's a problem when sharing the volume between 2 containers.

Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284484/docker-compose-share-named-volume-between-multiple-containers